# Integration of BOX, Google Drive and DropBox in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dropbox, google-drive-api

I want to integrate BOX, Google Drive and DropBox for uploading files from iPhone App and I had already go through "**filepicker.io"**.

But it allows only 5000 files/month for free.

So is there any library or API or anything available other than this, which is free and allow this integration from a single library or API?

I googled it a lot and also found APIs for integration but different one for all not from single library.

Comment: Why would there be?  Interacting with 3 very different APIs should logically require 3 different frameworks.  Write an umbrella framework.

Comment: @CodaFi : actually i'm developing a client based app for managing a huge event and he want all this for uploading files.

Comment: Trying to implement your own API over all three storage provider is a very risky challenge. While this is possible, the time and effort is certainly not justified. I would suggest, pay for an account from a provider where you can upload as much as you need and stick with just one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you integrate the cloud servers in you app through the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/) library. All of BOX, Cloud Drive, and Drop Box support and strive to be [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) so you could use the same approach to interact with all of them. The only difference between servers would be how to deal with athorization requests. Your REST requests and responses for uploading files would be handled by AFNetworking. AFNetworking is built on top of NSURLConnection and NSOperation and can also handle various authorization approaches such as [OAuth2](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client).

Hope this helps.
Cheers, Trond

Comment: AFNetworking does not "handle REST", rather you may implement an app-specific API (SDK, framework, library) for a RESTful web service utilizing AFNetworking. Of course, you can also implement an API for non-REST web-service APIs. The responsibility how to "handle" the semantics of HTTP requests, responses, status codes, response headers, response bodies etc. is up to the developer _alone_.

Comment: Agree with @CouchDeveloper - Implementing all these REST API's is a project on its own. A dedicated framework is very much necessary. And an umbrella SDK is even easier. 
I'm playing around with GDFileManagerKit which looks promising  http://www.grahamdennis.me/blog/2013/10/12/gdfilemanagerkit-a-consistent-ios-api-for-cloud-file-storage-services/